# Как вызвать свою функцию, после срабатывания функции в ng-submit?

Tags: angularjs

С angular не знаком вообщем, нужно не изменяя когда модуля и контролера текущего app(т.к. его формирует CMS автоматически), добавив JS код в footer страницы, определить, что после любой отправки формы, вызывать функцию alert('Привет');

Но если вы скажете, как можно вызвать свою внешнюю функцию, после срабатывания функции которая в контроллере angula, будет вообще супер!

Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Вот кусок кода, на который я хочу повлиять из вне (данный код я менять не могу), основная цель, после успешной отправки, вызвать свою функцию.

```js
 angular.module("website.widget.contact_form", ["core.library.jsonrpc", "ngFileUpload"]).service("widget.ContactForm.Service", ["jsonrpc", function(e) {
 var t = e.newService("Widget.ContactForm");
 this.sendMessage = t.createMethod("sendMessage"), this.getApiPath = e.getBasePath
}]).controller("widget.ContactForm.Controller", ["$scope", "$element", "widget.ContactForm.Service", "Upload", function(e, t, i, n) {
 function o() {
  e.emailError = !0, e.sending = !1
 }

 function r(t) {
  if (t.error) return o(t.error);
  e.emailSent = !0, e.triedToSend = !1, e.sending = !1
 }
 var a, s, l, c = t.find("input, textarea"),
  d = /^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$/;
 if (e.message = {}, e.placeholder = {}, e.hash = "", e.attachments = [], e.attachment = {}, c.length)
  for (var u = 0, m = c.length; u < m; u++)(s = (a = angular.element(c[u])).attr("name")) && (e.message[s] = e.message[s] || "", e.placeholder[s] = "checkbox" === s ? t.find(".moto-widget-contact_form-checkbox-text").text() || s : a.attr("placeholder") || s);
 e.validateEmailOnBlur = function() {
  e.contactForm.email.$pristine = !1, "" != e.contactForm.email.$viewValue ? d.test(e.contactForm.email.$viewValue) ? (e.contactForm.email.emailInvalid = !1, e.contactForm.email.$setValidity("pattern", !0)) : (e.contactForm.email.emailInvalid = !0, e.contactForm.email.$setValidity("pattern", !1)) : e.contactForm.email.emailInvalid = !1
 }, e.validateRequiredOnBlur = function(t) {
  e.contactForm[t].$pristine = !1, "" == e.contactForm[t].$viewValue ? (e.contactForm[t].$invalid = !0, e.contactForm.$valid = !1) : e.contactForm[t].$invalid = !1
 }, e.validate = function(t) {
  "email" == t && e.validateEmailOnBlur(), e.validateRequiredOnBlur(t)
 }, e.validateCheckbox = function() {
  l && (e.contactForm.checkbox.$pristine = !1, e.contactForm.checkbox.$viewValue ? (e.contactForm.checkbox.$invalid = !1, e.contactForm.checkbox.$setValidity("required", !0)) : (e.contactForm.checkbox.$invalid = !0, e.contactForm.checkbox.$setValidity("required", !1), e.contactForm.$valid = !1))
 }, e.checkboxChanged = function() {
  e.contactForm.checkbox.$invalid && e.validateCheckbox()
 }, e.requiredCheckbox = function() {
  l = !0
 }, e.errors = [], e.emailSent = !1, e.triedToSend = !1, e.submit = function() {
  e.sending || (e.emailSent = !1, e.triedToSend = !0, e.errors = [], e.sending = !0, e.emailError = !1, "object" == typeof e.contactForm.$error.required ? (e.contactForm.$error.required.forEach(function(e) {
   e.$dirty = !0, e.$pristine = !1, e.$setTouched()
  }), e.contactForm.$valid = !1) : e.contactForm.$valid = !0, e.validate("email"), e.validateCheckbox(),
   e.contactForm && e.contactForm.$valid && !e.contactForm.emailInvalid ? e.attachment.name ? (e.message._attachments = e.attachment.name ? 1 : 0, n.upload({
   method: "POST",
   url: i.getApiPath(),
   file: e.attachment,
   data: {
    jsonrpc: "2.0",
    id: 1,
    method: "Widget.ContactForm.sendMessage",
    params: {
     message: e.message,
     placeholder: e.placeholder,
     hash: e.hash
    }
   },
   headers: {
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
   }
  }).success(r).error(o)) : i.sendMessage({
   message: e.message,
   placeholder: e.placeholder,
   hash: e.hash
  }).success(r).error(o) : e.sending = !1)
 }
}])
```

Comment: Тут есть важный момент - форма отправляется через событие `submit`, которое потом перехватывается js, и отправляется Ajax. Или там просто кнопка, которая отправляет Ajax. По приведенному коду это не ясно.

Comment: И еще важный момент - вы хотите выполнять свой код, только после успешного ответа от сервера?

Comment: обычный submit и попытки туда вклинится ни к чему не приводят. я так понимаю ангуляр сразу перехватывает своим модулем. по нажатию на кнопку "отправить" тоже стоит событие по клику ng-click="submit();"

В идеале конечно после успешного ответа свою функцию запускать, но я буду рад, если получиться просто вклиниться, хотя бы в момент или после момента отправки, не важно успешно или не успешно.

Comment: Есть хороший способ, если вы знаете, какие обращения к АПИ вас интересуют. Это написать `interceptor` для ангуляра, который будет перехватывать ВСЕ запросы по AJAX. И среди этих всех запросов находить нужные вам и уже туда писать свою логику.

Comment: Если подкините пример такого перехвата, буду при много благодарен! :)

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors - официальная документация по interceptors. Если будет не понятно, накидаю пример.